# Pregunta Simple por PHP

Tags: php

Tengo esta variable extraida de MySQL,lo que quiero es que si es NOT NULL se vea en el PHP pero si es NULL no se vea ningun resultado en PhP es esto posible?

```
<? echo ''.$result21['Nombre_Esp'].'' ?>
```

En caso de ser positiva como debo colocar el resultado si Nombre_Esp no esta disponible

Comment: Ahi puse como hacer que no la muestre si es null, ahora esta parte: si Nombre_Esp no esta disponible que seria esa parte? traes de la base si esta disponible o no? si es asi, si tenes el valor de disponibilidad que hay que mostrar si NO ES NULL y NO ESTA DISPONIBLE? agrega toda esa info a la pregunta asi queda mas completa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proba de esta forma:

```
        <?php


            if(!is_null($result21['Nombre_Esp'])){
                echo $result21['Nombre_Esp'];
            } 

        }
```

Ejemplo rapido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: falta un ';' en la sentencia @Juan

Comment: Arreglado, muchas gracias @Neoniet

Answer (score 0):

Lo aconsejable sería realizar comprobaciones previas, primero si existe la variable (que pudiera darse el caso) y luego si es o no null.

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
if(isset($result21['Nombre_Esp'])) // Si está definida y no es null
{
        echo $result21['Nombre_Esp'];
}
else
{
        echo ' No existe la varible o es null';
}
```

El uso de !is_null por si sólo creo que se queda corto.

Answer (score 0):

Como vos sabes que la variable existe, porque es parte de la respuesta de tu query, no hace falta usar ninguna funcion adicional, directamente podes preguntar por la variable, y en caso de que sea `true` imprimís:

```
<?php if($result21['Nombre_Esp']) echo $result21['Nombre_Esp']; ?>
```